# Problem with using RTK Query and GraphQL with Access Token in Header

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, shopify-api

I'm currently facing an issue while using RTK Query with GraphQL and Access Token in the header. I have already tested the Access Token in Postman, and it works perfectly fine. However, I am unable to get it to work with RTK Query and GraphQL.

Whenever I try to run the query, I get an error saying "Non-serializable value was detected in the state." I believe this error is related to the Access Token. Here is the code that I am using:

Please help me, thank you.
Image:[ERROR MESSAGE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgvCS.png)

I tried everything but it gives everytime same error, tried using diffrent token, still error, maybe theres other or similar way to do this, i just want those Data,error and loader while using graphql, any recomendations?

```
import { createApi } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";
import { request, gql, ClientError } from "graphql-request";
const API_ENDPOINT = "https://c97663-2.myshopify.com/api/2023-01/graphql.json";
const graphqlBaseQuery =
  ({
    baseUrl,
    headers,
    method,
  }: {
    baseUrl: string;
    headers: any;
    method: string;
  }) =>
  async ({ body }: { body: string }) => {
    console.log("headers", headers); // log the headers being passed to the request function
    try {
      const result = await request(baseUrl, body, headers);
      return { data: result };
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof ClientError) {
        const status = error.response.status;
        const data = error.response.data;
        if (status === 403 && data?.extensions?.code === "ACCESS_DENIED") {
          return { error: { status, data: { message: "Access denied" } } };
        } else {
          return { error: { status, data: error } };
        }
      }
      return { error: { status: 500, data: error } };
    }
  };

export const productsApi = createApi({
  baseQuery: graphqlBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: API_ENDPOINT,
    headers: {
      "X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token": "07a059546dee3d048794dc7744f6183a",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    method: "POST",
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getProducts: builder.query({
      query: () => ({
        body: gql`
          query {
            products(first: 10) {
              edges {
                node {
                  id
                  title
                  description
                  productType
                  tags
                  availableForSale
                  createdAt
                  variants(first: 1) {
                    edges {
                      node {
                        id
                        sku
                        title
                        priceV2 {
                          amount
                          currencyCode
                        }
                        image {
                          originalSrc
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        `,
      }),
      transformResponse: (response) => {
        if (response.errors) {
          return { error: { status: response.status } };
        }
        return { data: response.data };
      },
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useGetProductsQuery } = productsApi;
```

Answer (score 0):

First You need to define the **headers** in the separate file then you can import in the file where you defining the **graphqlBaseQuery** :-

Like this below :-

```
const apiHeaders = {
  "X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token": "07a059546dee3d048794dc7744f6183a",
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
};

export default apiHeaders;
```

other file where you defines the **graphqlBaseQuery**-:

```js
import apiHeaders from './apiHeaders';

const graphqlBaseQuery =

  ({ baseUrl, method }: { baseUrl: string; method: string }) =>

  async ({ body }: { body: string }) => {

    console.log("headers", apiHeaders); // log the headers being passed to the request function

    try {
      const result = await request(baseUrl, body, {
        headers: apiHeaders,
        method,
      });

      return { data: result };

    } catch (error) {
      // error handling code
    }
  };
```

Comment: Thank you for help, i just fixed it using apollo client. Its better. Thank you anyway